# Socket Programming in Python raising error socket.error:< [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed

Tags: python, sockets

I am new to Socket Programming. I have implemented the client and server script for transferring the file over internet. Both scripts are working on Local Area Network computers. I have tried to exchange the files in Local area network from 1MB to 1GB, the scripts are running fine.

But When I am using both the script to work on different network means internet. It's not working. I have checked the firewall rules of both system. Python is allowed. Here is the code snippet. Can someone tell me what is the problem ?

```
Script -> Server.py

import os
import socket
file_path = r'C:\Users\Baby\Downloads\006.jpg'
file_size = str(os.path.getsize(file_path))
file_name = file_path.split('\\')[-1]
# print file_name.encode('UTF-8')
total = file_name+ '/'+file_size
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
# value of host = '103.235.165.205' as this is my ip which i am using in client.py
s.bind((host,21000))
s.listen(5)

print 'Server is listening on {}:21000'.format(host)
conn,addr = s.accept()
print 'Got connection from IP :{} Host :{}'.format(addr[0],addr[1])
conn.send(total.encode())

with open(file_path,'rb') as data:
    while data:
        conn.send((data.read()))
        break
    conn.close()
print 'transfer complete'
s.close()
```

---

```
Script -> Client.py

import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('10.174.238.205',21000))
total = (s.recv(1024)).decode()
file_name , file_size = map(str,total.split('/'))
data = s.recv(int(file_size.decode()))
with open(file_name,'wb') as getfile:
    getfile.write(data)
```

Comment: I assume the error is displayed on the Client machine, right?    Can you ping the server from the client?   How many network adapters are there on the server?  Can you use Telnet to connect to the server's host:port address?

Comment: @DaleWilson Yes ! Sir, the errors are displayed in the every machine where I used to run client script. I have tried to telnet on socket pair and it's not working. More over there are two adapters in the System , but one machine is using USB dongle for internet access. Does this socket stuff depends on the network adapter also ? If yes please elaborate ?

Comment: @AkshaySingh Are you sure you are connecting to the correct ip address from the client? from what it looks u try to connect to `10.174.238.250` however in your server code it says the host should be `103.235.165.205`

Comment: @DaleWilson That's just a simple mistake I know that the IP should be same for listening and connecting, that's not an issue, I have checked it but not working.

Comment: 10.174.238.205 is a private address; it's not reachable over the public Internet.  You would need a static IP address, or some sort of dynamic DNS service to get a publicly-usable address for your server.

Comment: @jasonharper means like we are using in the web servers in AWS or AZURE

Comment: @AkshaySingh When you listen for a connection you will be listening on one of the network adapters in your machine (the bind() call determines which one)  You must bind the listen socket to the network adapter that is attached to the network where the client(s) are running.

Comment: Thank you @DaleWilson I will check the documentation. If you have any resource then please share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each network adapter in the server should be associated with its own iP address.

The s.bind() command should use the IP or host name associated with the network adapter on which you wish to listen for a connector.  This should be an adapter attached to the network on which the clients are running.

Also if the connection is going out side the local network, you must be using an IP that is publicly visible.  You can read about IP assignments [here](https://www.iana.org/numbers) and many other places (Google is your friend).   Normally public IP addresses will be assigned by your ISP (sometimes for additional cost since they are a scarce resource.)

Thanks to @jasonharper for pointing out the public vs private IP issue in a comment.